# When I select default value in drop down render full form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in drop down. When I select default value --select-- in drop down it render whole form.

```
<%= render 'leave_applies/sidebar' %>
<% content_for :script do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :leave_applies %>
<% end %>
<div class='row-fluid clear'>
  <div class='box gradient'>
    <div class='title'>
      <h3 style='margin-left:1em'>Leave Summary</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class="control-group string optional student_gender">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="student_gender">Teacher Code</label>
    <div class="controls">
   <%= select_tag "leaves", options_from_collection_for_select(Teacher.all, "id", "teacher_code"), :prompt => "--Select Employee No--" %>
   </div>
   </div>

 <div id = "leaves_apply">
 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code when I select "--Select Employee No--" it render whole page

[image]

Js code

```
$("#leaves").change(function(){
  var url = '/leave_summary?summary=' + $(this).val()+''
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'html',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
      $("#leaves_apply").html(data);  
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: might be you have added onchange event in your js,your js code will help further

Comment: I have included js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check before submitting ajax request wether value is empty or not based on that fire ajax query

```
$("#leaves").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != "" )
  {
    var url = '/leave_summary?summary=' + $(this).val()+''
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'html',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
      $("#leaves_apply").html(data);  
     }
    });
  }
})
```